# Issues converting obj c methods to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mwphotobrowser

I am trying to implement these delegate methods for the MWPhoto Framework ([find it here](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)) in Swift.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser;
- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

I have written these methods below but my controller is telling me it still does not conform to the delegate methods.

```
func numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser(photoBrowser: MWPhotoBrowser) -> Int {
    return self.photos.count
}


func photoBrowserphotoAtindex(photoBrowser:MWPhotoBrowser, index:Int) -> (MWPhoto?){
    if(index < self.photos.count){
        return self.photos[index]
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Probably you should return `NSUinteger` instead of `Int`? No sure whether the optional is correct in the 2nd one.

Comment: found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086440/swift-converting-between-uint-and-int

Comment: found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086440/swift-converting-between-uint-and-int